# Spring 3.1 MVC and Security: both login and registration form (multiple forms) on same page get submitted

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-3

I'm using Spring (3.1), Spring MVC (3.1) and Spring Security (3.0) in combination and I've put together a single JSP page that has two forms on it; One is a form to login and the other is a form to register (i.e. create a new user).

For the register form, I use the Spring `form` tags, backed up by a controller to handle the request but for the login form I don't bother with the Spring `form` tags as I don't believe they're needed. There is also no controller that I need to write to handle the form submission as Spring Security takes care of authenticating so long as the request is submitted to `j_spring_security_check`.

The register form is working fine but the login form is a problem. It seems that when I click the submit button on the login form, the registration form is also submitted, or at least Spring thinks I'm trying to submit that form. Here is the JSP:

```
    <form id="loginform" method="POST" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>">
        <label for="existing_email">Email:</label> 
        <input name="j_username" id="existing_email" type="text" value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME}" /> 

        <label for="existing_password">Password:</label> 
        <input name="j_password" id="existing_password" type="password" /> 

        <input id="login-form-submit" type="submit" value="Sign in" />
    </form>

    <form:form id="registrationform" modelAttribute="user" method="POST" action="register">
        <form:label path="username" for="email">Email:</form:label> 
        <form:input path="username" name="username" id="email" type="text" /> 
        <form:errors path="username" cssClass="formError" />

        <form:label path="password" for="password">Password:</form:label>
        <form:input path="password" name="password" id="password" type="password" />
        <form:errors path="password" cssClass="formError" />

        <input id="registration-form-submit" type="submit" value="Sign up" />
    </form:form>
```

Notice that `form` tags for the **input of type submit** are not present and this seems to be a normal thing to do in the examples I've seen. Adding form tags to the submit button I guess doesn't make sense as it doesn't map to anything on the target object (*user* in this case).

When I click the "Sign in" button I get the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/project1] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/registration.jsp at line 29
28:         <form:form id="registrationform" modelAttribute="user" method="POST" action="register">
29:             <form:label path="username" for="username">Username:</form:label> 
30:             <form:input path="username" name="username" id="username" type="text" />
31:             <form:errors path="username" cssClass="formError" />
32:              


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
```

This I recognise from cases where you forget to include the modelAttribute attribute in `form:form`, but of course I don't want to submit this form to my controller.

I have a feeling there is a mistake I'm making or a simple solution. Can anyone recommend a way around this or perhaps a different approach?

Here is the controller method that handles requests to register in case that's needed:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "**/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute("user") @Validated User user, BindingResult errors, ModelMap model) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "registration";
        }
        // Other stuff then...
        return "profile"
    }
```

Comment: Where are you redirecting user after a successful/unsuccessful login?

Comment: A successful login serves up a different jsp page but a failed one serves the same page i.e. registration.jsp.

Comment: Actually Ritesh, that's given me a clue and it seems the problem is when the login fails and I redirect to the same JSP, albeit through a different controller method. I'll add an answer myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using "user" modelAttribute in form tag then a non-null request attribute *must* be present with name "user".

One way to add that in request attribute is what you did in your answer above. Other ways are:

(1)  Add in ModelMap:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginFailed(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    model.addAttribute("error", "true");
    return "registration";
}
```

(2) Add in request scope (Using WebRequest or HttpServletRequest):

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginFailed(ModelMap model, WebRequest webRequest) {
   webRequest.setAttribute("user", new User(), WebRequest.SCOPE_REQUEST);
    model.addAttribute("error", "true");
    return "registration";
}
```

(3)  Use @ModelAttribute on method:

```
    @ModelAttribute("user")
public User user() {
    return new User();
}
```

Please also see [Using @ModelAttribute on a method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods) and [Using @ModelAttribute on a method argument](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args)

Also note that you don't have to use type attribute. See [form:input](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.input) and [form:password](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.password).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is specifically when a login fails and the same page is served up, albeit on a different URL path and so through a different controller method. Therefore my original suspicion that the issue is that both forms are submitted may be something of a red herring, though I still don't fully understand what's going on and that may yet have something to do with it. In any case, this is what corrected the problem for me:

I had a controller method that originally looked like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginFailed(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("error", "true");
    return "registration";
}
```

In the Spring Security context I specify `/loginfailed` as the path to go to by default if a login attempt fails. This is where it seems the user object is needed so if I alter the signature as follows it all works:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginFailed(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult errors, ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("error", "true");
    return "registration";
}
```

Any comments/clarification welcome from others.

Comment: As mentioned in http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args, "An @ModelAttribute on a method argument indicates the argument should be retrieved from the model. If not present in the model, the argument should be instantiated first and then added to the model." Since you are not binding request parameters, your solution is equivalent to adding new User object in model. Also, the BindingResult in not needed in signature.